# Select Map marker with reticle in android MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, markers

My application requires that a user select a location on a MapView.  I will be using Google Places API to place location markers on the map. There will be times however when a user might select a location, for example a fountain in a park, that IS NOT listed in the Places API.  One option is to offer users a choice of selecting a location with a touch on a map, OR selecting map markers of known locations using two different maps for each activity.  I think the perfect solution however would be to use one MapView that contains the mapmarkers but also allow the user to select a location that does not have an associated marker.

My thoughts were to apply a reticle in it's own Overlay that stays centered in the middle of the MapView despite scrolling and a select button to make the selection.

If the reticle is over a marker, for example, Sams Cafe', then the button would read "Select Sam's Cafe'", if the reticle isn't over any Map Markers, then the button would read "Select this location".

I am having trouble figuring out a way to verify the reticle is over a marker.  Since the marker is limited to a single GeoPoint, it's going to be very difficult, frustrating and time consuming for the user to try and match the reticle center to the exact GeoPoint.

What would be optimal is a check to see if the reticle is over the Map Marker graphic.  I presume this will utilize projections and bounds??

Two questions, How to do this if possible?
or, is there a better UI that I am overlooking that is much easier to achieve?

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the way you saying is better than anyone, but why dont you keep away any user from any kind of geocoding. Like user selects the location through marker, on the basis of that user will confirm the location, if it has got any place then it will show the address or it will show the nearby location. e.g. let the user select the location from marker get the longs. and lats. , If user confirms that location then put it onto geocoding and get the location address, it will surely return an address maybe exact or nearby and if user likes it, user will confirm it, simple. Please notify if its not feasible way.

Comment: The program design requires that the user can select any geopoint on the google MapView.  This is required.  IF that geopoint happens to represent a location such as a business, or park, then that data will be used as well.  As I understand it, pure reverse geocoding won't give me the name of a business.. only the address.  This is why we are using Google Places API.

Comment: I guess an option is to allow the user to pick a geopoint with a touch, then run a match against business addresses and if there is a match, then offer that business as an option.

Comment: Another possibility is to use two layers.  One layer responds to user touch, the other displays the markers and is located on top.  Therefore there should be a way to "intercept" a marker selection before a general touch selection.. I think.